# Enum.filter/3 is undefined or private

Tags: elixir

I was using Enum inside a function and it's shows me the error, I have tried different approach but didn't get the solution. Can anyone please help, I am totally noob in Elixir,

```elixir
def matrix_of_sum do
 [
 [21 ,"na", "na", "na", 12],
 ["na", "na", 12, "na", "na"],
 ["na", "na", "na", "na", "na"],
 [17, "na", "na", "na", "na"],
 ["na", 22, "na", -1, "na"]
 ] end
```

```elixir
def valid_sum do
for row <- matrix_of_sum, cell <- row do
  if cell != "na" && cell>0 do
    #store in new list
    store(cell)
    #|>
    # IO.inspect(cell)
  end
 end 
end
```

```elixir
def store(cell) do
 list = []
 list = cell
 IO.puts(list) |>Enum.filter(list ,& !is_nil(&1))
end
```

Answer (score 1):

`IO.puts(list) |> Enum.filter(list, &!is_nil(&1))` attempts to call `Enum.filter/3` with arguments `:ok, list, &!is_nil(&1)` because you pipe the result of `IO.puts/1` to `Enum.filter`.

BTW, `IO.puts/1` would not work as well, because `List` does not implement [`String.Chars`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/String.Chars.html) protocol.

If you want to print the result and then pipe it into [`Enum.filter/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#filter/2), you might do:

```elixir
list |> IO.inspect() |> Enum.reject(&is_nil/1)

# or
# list |> IO.inspect() |> Enum.filter(&!is_nil(&1))
```

See documentation on [`IO.inspect/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/IO.html#inspect/2) for details.

Comment: I have tried it is showing                                                       
(Protocol.UndefinedError) protocol Enumerable not implemented for 21 of type Integer. This protocol is implemented for the following type(s): Date.Range, File.Stream, Function, GenEvent.Stream, HashDict, HashSet, IO.Stream, List, Map, MapSet, Range, Stream

Comment: Which means your variable `list` does not contain a list, obviously.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to put the output results into the list

Comment: You could use `List.wrap/1` https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/List.html#wrap/1 to ensure that the value is wrapped as a list. `List.wrap(21)` yields `[21]`, but if the thing is already a list, it emerges unchanged, e.g. `List.wrap(["x"])` yields `["x"]`